# Building a portfolio: use ng-repeat but each item has own page

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS, and need some guidance on building a portfolio site:

- main.html > use ng-repeat for each piece of work, currently each ng-href
  points to "work" but I'd like each work to get its own URL, for
  example ng-href="work#{{title}}"
- Each 'work' contains about 5-6 images and text. There are all similar in terms of HTML elements, but the images and text is different. So maybe a template would work here.

Here is my code so far

**index.js**

```
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })     
  .state('work', {
    url: '/work',
    templateUrl: 'app/work/work.html',
    controller: 'WorkCtrl'
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

});

**main.html**

```
  <section ng-repeat="work in works | orderBy:'rank'" class="showcase {{work.class}}">
<a ng-href="#/work">
  <hgroup>
  <h4>{{work.title}}</h4>
  <p>{{work.sub}}</p>
  </hgroup>
</a>
```

**main.controller.js**

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.works = [
  {
    'key': 'title-1',
    'title': 'A piece of work',
    'url': 'page1.html',
    'description': 'A long piece of text goes in here',
    'logo': 'image-1.png'
  },
  {
    'key': 'title-2',
    'title': 'A piece of work number 2',
    'url': 'page2.html',
    'description': 'A long piece of text goes in here',
    'logo': 'image-2.png'
  }, 
  ...
];
angular.forEach($scope.works, function(work) {
  work.rank = Math.random();
});
```

});

**work.html**
Not sure how to go about building a template what can fetch the data from MainCtrl, or should I be using a JSON object and remove the data from main.controller and have both of them reference this data. In any case this template only needs to show one portfolio work not all like the main.controller.js.

**work.controller.js**
Not sure what to do here, i think i need to configure a path that gets each item id and a directive, but again, this will take me days to figure out on my own.

Hope you can help out. I'm a beginner so examples would be most appreciated. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where to get the common data for both templates...
There's a couple of considerations will you do an ajax request to get the data?

**NO**: Create a factory and store all your data there

```
angular.module('mod').factory('worksData', function(){
   var works = []

   function getWorks(){
     return works;
   }

   return {
       getWorks: getWorks
   }   
 }
```

**YES**:

- use ui-router 'resolve'
- create an abstract state and a controller for it to...
- store the data to the same factory

I am not going in depth because it might not be what you need.
Not sure what you meant with your 2nd question.

Comment: Thanks gsalisi for your suggestion.  I'm a beginner so it's easier if I don't use ajax, right?

There is one thing I'm not sure about -  I'm using ng-repeat on the [home] page to generate each [work] item (this appears as a list), but how do i route each [work] separately but just use one template for all the work? 

`<a ng-href="#/work/{{work.url}}">`

Here is an example of a site, which does not use Angular, but follows the same logic I'm trying to achieve: http://www.bendavidsandhu.com/

Comment: not sure i had more than one question, it all falls under the problem of "main index shows a list of work using ng-repeat" and "work.html shows one item of work from which the user clicked on from the main index page" and how to connect the two, so my code is DRY.

Comment: What you said should work fine but on your stateProvider you need to have -- state('work.id',{url:/:id, ...}) now you can access this work id using $stateParams on the controller you attach to it. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#basic-parameters Then you can use this id to fetch the appropriate from a service.

Comment: Ah, yes using `:id` should solve this problem. Then will link it to a service. Hopefully smooth sailing from here on. Cheers.